# Oracle SQL Transaction with INSERT

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a database of warehouse of groceries. I have tables `clients, workers, orders, products` and some which are not really important in that question.

I want to avoid a problem where client makes a *new order for product* but there isn't enough amount of this product in our warehouse.

I have to make a transaction which avoid situation when two clients are making a new order at the same time and one of them ordered for example the last item while making order by the second client.

I don't really know how to do it because only workers can decrease amount of every product. So I want so that while deleting a order (which was made by client) by worker the amount of available product was decreased.

I know that I can put it into trigger but the question is:

> how to define the transaction of ordering product with checking available amount. Should I count the difference between avalaible
>   amount in table Products and amount of ordered product by the
>   time(unrealized orders).

How to do it ?

Comment: can you post your sample data and expected outcome ? that would be easier for solution.

Comment: Why not consider to have a virtual column (if the database is 11g and above)?

Answer (score 0):

for orders, you have to manage Stock of that product and every time when someone going to make an order you have to check product availability or not.

Comment: this is not a proper answer. It doesn't provide useful information to author. Please consider to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is place a trigger on the `orders` table, that subtracts quantity from the `products` table and raises an exception if the amount is negative. The trigger would have like:

```
update products set current_quantity = current_quantity - :new.amount_purchased
 where id = :new.product_id
returning current_quantity into l_current_quantity;

if l_current_quantity < 0 then
    raise_application_error( -20001, 'Amount ordered larger than remaining quantity.' );
end if;
```

You'll have to handle the exception in your ordering procedure.